# PHP Search all array values into another each array value

Tags: php, arrays

OK here is what i want to do

I have an array that contains keywords

```
$keywords = array('sport','messi','ronaldo','Barcelona','madrid','club','final','cup','player');
```

and i have another array that contains my whole titles

let's say

```
$titles = array('Real Madrid is the only club to have kept a European cup by winning it five times in a row.','Cristiano Ronaldo is World Soccer's Player of the Year 2013.','Lionel Messi Reaches $50 Million-A-Year Deal With Barcelona','','');
```

so now what i want to do

is to loop my keywords array in each of the titles array element

and if there is 3 keywords in one element then do something

for example

```
$titiles[0] // this one has these words => Madrid , cup club
```

so this one is have at least 3 words of my keywords

so if each element has 3 keywords or more , then echo that array element.

any idea on how to get this working?

Comment: loop titles, explode on space, run array_intersect() on the exploded vs $keywords count() result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($titles as $t){

$te=explode(' ',$t);

$c=count(array_intersect($te,$keywords));

if($c >=3){
echo $t.' has 3 or more matches';
}

}
```

live demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/7kUUEK

2 matches is your current max

if you want **Madrid** to match **madrid**

```
$keywords=array_map('strtolower', $keywords);
foreach ($titles as $t){

$te=explode(' ',$t);
$comp=array_map('strtolower', $te);

$c=count(array_intersect($comp,$keywords));



   if($c >=3){
   echo $t.' has 3 or more matches';
   }

}
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/itdegA

Comment: Beat me to it by a mouse click :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could also use `substr_count()` to get the number of occurances. Consider this example:

```
$keywords = array('sport','messi','ronaldo','Barcelona','madrid','club','final','cup','player');
$titles = array('Real Madrid is the only club to have kept a European cup by winning it five times in a row.',"Cristiano Ronaldo is World Soccer's Player of the Year 2013.","Lionel Messi Reaches $50 Million-A-Year Deal With Barcelona",'','');
$count = 0;
$data = array();
foreach($titles as $key => $value) {
    $value = strtolower($value);
    $keys = array_map('strtolower', $keywords);
    foreach($keys as $needle) {
        $count+= substr_count($value, $needle);
    }
    echo "In title[$key], the number of occurences using keywords = " .$count . '<br/>';
    $count = 0;
}
```

Sample Output:

```
In title[0], the number of occurences using keywords = 3
In title[1], the number of occurences using keywords = 2
In title[2], the number of occurences using keywords = 2
In title[3], the number of occurences using keywords = 0
In title[4], the number of occurences using keywords = 0
```

[**Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AqL8EQ)

Comment: Thanks buddy , but why you wrote $count again at the end of the first foreach loop

Comment: @HasanZohdy Your welcome, it just resets the counter. foreach piece of the title there is each count. so after the iteration of a title you need to reset it to prepare it for the next one

Comment: just setting it once, before the 2nd foreach would make more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler with array_intersect:

```
$keywords = array('sport','messi','ronaldo','Barcelona','madrid','club','final','cup','player');

$titles = array('Real Madrid is the only club to have kept a European cup by winning it five times in a row.','Cristiano Ronaldo is World Soccer\'s Player of the Year 2013.','Lionel Messi Reaches $50 Million-A-Year Deal With Barcelona');

foreach($titles as $title) {
    if (count(array_intersect(explode(' ',strtolower($title)), $keywords)) >= 3) {
        //stuff
    }
}
```